# ajax redirect if host not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How do I redirect a client page if the host is unreachable?  My code works if host is reachable but does nothing when it isn't:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){      
    $.ajax({url: "http://www.espnsdsd.com",
            dataType: "jsonp",

            complete: function(e, xhr, settings){
    if(e.status === 200){
        window.location.replace('http://www.espn.com'); 

    }else{
        window.location.replace('http://www.anotherespn.com'); 
    }
}


     });
});
```

Comment: [Same origin policy...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: So it's not possible?

Comment: If the domain you are checking does not allow CORs, you are out of luck.

Comment: I can ask the domain owners to allow CORs.  In that case, what is the best way to achieve this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using the error function. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){      
  $.ajax({url: "http://www.espnsdsd.com",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    complete: function(e, xhr, settings){
      if(e.status === 200){
        window.location.replace('http://www.espn.com'); 
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      window.location.replace("http://www.anotherespn.com");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Then it is a CORs problem. On the domain your trying to redirect to, you will need to send back some headers.

    `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
    `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, content-type`
    `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS`